# Django: como hacer sub-formularios para las foreing keys

Tags: python, django, formularios

estoy aprendiendo a usar Django para implementarlo como GUI para una aplicación.

En la base de datos tengo dos tablas:

Por un lado `domicilios_domicilio`, que consta de una PK serial para el ID y algunos varchar para los datos del domicilio y por otro, `personas_persona`, la cual consta de una PK serial para el ID, algunos varchar para los datos de la persona y una FK con el ID de domicilio.

Cuando creo la página para crear una nueva persona utilizando ModelForm me permite elegir un domicilio existente, sin embargo quisiera agregar la opción de crear un nuevo domicilio desde allí mismo (similar a como se hace desde `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`) ya que, si bien esto es un formulario muy simple y de prueba, sería muy engorroso tener que solicitarle al usuario que vaya creando uno a uno los campos desde el más simple al mas complejo en la aplicación real.

Desde ya muchas Gracias...

Dejo los códigos por si son necesarios:

```
def nueva_persona(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formaPersona = PersonaForm(request.POST)
        if formaPersona.is_valid():
            formaPersona.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        formaPersona = PersonaForm()
    return render(request, 'personas/nuevo.html', {'formaPersona': formaPersona})
```

```
class DomicilioForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Domicilio
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'nro_calle': TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number'}),
        }


class PersonaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'type': 'email'}),
        }
```

**EDIT:**
Algo así es lo que quiero hacer:

Cuando el usuario quiere añadir un objeto de clase persona se mostraría un formulario como el siguiente:
[image: Formulario para añadir objeto de clase Persona]

Al presionar el botón `+` al lado de la lista desplegable de objetos clase Domicilio se debería abrir un pop-up con el formulario para crear objetos de clase Domicilio:
[image: Formulario en pop-up para añadir objeto clase Domicilio]

Answer (score 0):

Para crear "sub-formularios" de un algún FK solo debe crear otro formulario y pasarle el campo que va a llenar, e igualmente su url y su view, aquí un ejemplo:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class TipoColor(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.color

class Usuario(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    color = models.ForeignKey(TipoColor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Usuario, TipoColor


class FormUsuario(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = '__all__'


class FormTipocolor(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TipoColor
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
data = {
    'formu':FormUsuario()}
if request.method == 'POST':
    formulario = FormUsuario(data=request.POST)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
    else:
        data['formu']=formulario
return render(request, 'registrar/register.html', data)

def color(request):
data = {
    'formu':FormTipocolor(data=request.POST)}
if request.method == 'POST':
    formulario = FormTipocolor(data=request.POST)
    if formulario.is_valid():
        formulario.save()
    else:
        data['formu']=formulario
return render(request, 'registrar/color.html', data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from registrar import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('registrar/', views.register, name='registrar'),
    path('color/', views.color, name='color'),
]
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Estuve revisando y lo que tengo hecho es igual a lo que me propones, sin embargo lo que yo quiero hacer es que al abrir la página para crear un nuevo objeto de la clase que contiene la FK, se muestren unos botones, al lado del campo de lista donde se muestran los objetos de la clase "inferior", que den las opciones de crear/editar/eliminar un objetos de esa otra clase (de la misma forma que lo hace la página /admin de django). Saludos y gracias.

Comment: En pocas palabras lo que buscas hacer es un CRUD para la FK?

Comment: claro, dentro del formulario de creación de un nuevo objeto de la clase "superior" (en mi caso Persona) dar las opciones de abrir un pop-up (o un div en el mismo formulario) para crear/editar/eliminar un objeto de la clase "inferior" (en mi caso Domicilio). Así no es necesario crear un objeto Domicilio y luego un objeto Persona, sino hacerlo todo en un mismo formulario... Saludos y gracias...

Comment: En el post agregué un EDIT al final con capturas del `/admin` de django para que se entienda mejor